# Is it possible to hide the x-axis line in aChart engine line graph?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am implementing an aChartEngine line graph. In this app I just want to display the x-axis **values** according to their positions and **not** display the x-axis line how can I do that?
*How can I hide the x-axis line?*

Answer (score 4):

Use this code
  `renderer.setShowAxes(false);` see the magic your all axis will invisible..

Answer (score 1):

use the method of XYMultipleSeriesRenderer `renderer.setShowLegend(false);` it hides the legends of axis [check this method setShowLegend(boolean)](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.html#setShowLegend%28boolean%29)